# Sort a filtered array with a higher order function in computed properties [vue.js]

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js, vuejs2, higher-order-functions

I want to switch between different sorting methods to sort an array by numbers, dates and titles and so on.

I want to store all sort methods in the created hook as higher order functions:

```
created () {
    this.sortings = [
      {
        asc: (img1, img2) => img2[this.sortBy] - img1[this.sortBy],
        desc: (img1, img2) => img1[this.sortBy] - img2[this.sortBy],
        compare: (a, b) => a.ratio - b.ratio
      }
    ]
}
```

my computed property looks like this:

```
  computed: {
    resultsFiltered () {
        return this.imgData.filter(...).sort(this.sortings[this.sortMethod])
      }
    }
  },
```

My goal is to switch the sorting by changing the `sortMethod` in the Data object:

```
data () {
  return {
   sortMethod: "compare" // or "asc", "desc",
   sortBy: "ratio" // or "date", "title", "filesize", ...
 }
}
```

How can I reach the higher order function in 'these.sortings' to sort my computed property?

Also, I don't know how to pass the parameters to the sorting functions :/

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a reactivity working you should place this.sortings in the data section.
Also you need to correct this.sortings if you wish it to work like a dictionary:

```
this.sortings = {
        asc: (img1, img2) => img2[this.sortBy] - img1[this.sortBy],
        desc: (img1, img2) => img1[this.sortBy] - img2[this.sortBy],
        compare: (a, b) => a.ratio - b.ratio
      }
```

Parameters to a comparator function is passed by the array's sort method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think my problem is that array syntax arround my `this.sortings`. I will try to clean it up. I will post the result later if its works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.customSort = function (key, order='asc') {
  let arrayOfObject = [...this]
  let compare = (a,b) => {
    if (a[key] < b[key]) {
      return order === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (a[key] > b[key]) {
      return order === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0
  }
  return arrayOfObject.sort(compare)
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
 
  data: {
    filteredArray: [
      { serialNo: 1, date: '1994-12-20', title: 'big title' },
      { serialNo: 2, date: '1994-12-22', title: 'small title' },
      { serialNo: 3, date: '1993-12-20', title: 'large title' },
      { serialNo: 4, date: '1992-12-20', title: 'mid title' },
      { serialNo: 5, date: '1991-12-20', title: 'great title' },
      { serialNo: 6, date: '1994-10-20', title: 'awesome title' }
    ],
    currentKey: 'serialNo',
    currentOrder: 'asc'
  },
  
  computed: {
    getSortedFilteredArray () {
      return this.filteredArray.customSort(this.currentKey, this.currentOrder)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <!-- CHOOSE KEY TO SORT -->
  <span>Select key: </span>
  <button @click="currentKey = 'serialNo'">serialNo</button> | 
  <button @click="currentKey = 'date'">date</button> | 
  <button @click="currentKey = 'title'">title</button>
  <br/>
  
  <!-- CHOOSE ORDER TO SORT -->
  <span>Select order: </span>
  <button @click="currentOrder = 'asc'">asc</button> |
  <button @click="currentOrder = 'desc'">desc</button>
  <br/>
  
  <!-- SELECTED SORT / ORDER -->
  <span>Current key : {{ currentKey }}</span> |
  <span>Current order : {{ currentOrder }}</span>
  
  <!-- SORTED RESULT -->
  <ul>
    <li 
      v-for="(obj, i) in getSortedFilteredArray"
      :key="i"
    >
      {{ obj }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It helps me to get a better understanding of sorting in Vue. I will consider it for future sorting features.